# How do you ask for data object from another class?

Tags: java, android

Let's say, I have this code that requests for value from a listener.

```
Response response = new Response();
int result = listener.callback(response);
if(result == 0) { // result can 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
    // process $response from listener
}
else if(result == 1) {
    // try someting else
}
...
else {
    // show error
}
```

I expect that the `listener` will populate the `response` parameter I passed into the callback.

I am thinking to simply write something like this:

```
Response response = listener.callback();
```

But I need the `int result` to determine what to do with the `response` so I don't like this approach.

Any standard way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need the result value to be an int and use that to decide what to do? That reeks of bad design, or of a C programmer writing code in Java. If you need to be able to do different things with the response, create an inheritance hierarchy in which different classes do different things with the response, and if you still need a specific value to decide which one to call, make that value a field of the response, use a factory pattern, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `result` field *(int, string, enum, w/e suits you)* into the `Response` class, and update that as well as with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some result code into your Response class.

If Response is not your class there is multiple options:

1.You can create your own class with result code and extends from Response

```
    class MyResponse extends Response {
      public int result;
    }
```

2.You can create your own class with result code and have Response as another atribute

```
    class MyResponse{
      public int result;
      public Response response;
    }
```

3. You can use Pair type as your return type from callback with result code and Response type

   ```
    Pair<Integer, Response> result = listener.callback();
   ```